# Make 2 arrays from one array

Tags: java

I have this array:

```
int[] arr = {-1, -2, 0, 1, 2};
```

From this array I have to make 2 arrays: one with negative elements and another with the positive ones.

I tried the code below, but it doesn't work — it fills the array that I made with 0 for the numbers that are positive:

```
 int[] arr1 = new int[arr.length];
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                if(arr[i]<0)
                arr1[i]=arr[i];
            System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(arr1));
```

Comment: And what did you try?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Looping through elements and putting into new arrays based on their value is one solution.

Comment: simple create 2 array put negative elements in first  and another with the positive.

Comment: @MihaiRO Please edit your question and put the code in there, not into a comment.

Comment: That's great you have some code now, but explain what "doesn't work" means. That tell us nothing about what the problem could be.

Comment: You can't put the negative number you find at offset `i` in `arr` at offset `i` in `arr1`. You need to know how many negative and positive numbers there are so you can size the arrays appropriately, and you have to have separate indices for putting the numbers into those other arrays.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
int[] arr= {-1, -2, 0, 1, 2};
int p=0;
int n=0;

for(int i=0; i<arr.length-1; ++i) {
  if(arr[i]>=0) {
    p=p+1;
  } else {
    n=n+1;
  }
}

int[] posarr=new int[p];
int[] negarr=new int[n];
p=0;
n=0;
for(int i=0; i<arr.length-1; ++i) {
  if(arr[i]>=0) {
    posarr[p]=arr[i];
    p=p+1;
  } else {
    negarr[n]=arr[i];
    n=n+1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Arrays have fixed size. Also they don't have `lenght()` method, but `length` field.

Comment: @Pshemo I have been programming to much in C++, I thought the same thing for vectors, or .size(), would work for arrays in java, will edit

Comment: Arrays also have a fixed size in C++.

Comment: @DavidConrad Vectors do not.

Comment: @msleevi Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at test.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:25)
Java Result: 1

Comment: `i < arr.length - 1` This will skip the last element in the array.

Comment: @msleevi --- at int posarr=new int[p];
int negarr=new int[n]; and posarr[p]=arr[i]; posarr[p]=arr[i]; I get array required but int foud.

Comment: @MihaiRO Alright, now try it. Sorry, my java is terrible.

Comment: Done it is good but as David sayd that -1 in i < arr.length - 1 will skyp the last element. TY